# Search Navigation (Verticals) Specific to Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a questions about the Search Navigation Web Part. I have created 5 search verticals (Everything, All Issues, All Plans, My Issues, My Plans). I have a separate page for each vertical. I want to know if it is possible to only show 3 search verticals depending on what page you are on.

**Example:** 
If I am on a Issues page I would only like to see Everything, All Issues, and My Issues. If I am on the Plans page, I would only like to see Everything, All Plans, My Plans.

How can accomplish this in SharePoint 2013?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use JavaScript on each page and hide it on page load.

Comment: Is there an example on how to do this? I guess my question is how do you select the page? @AmalHashim

Comment: On each page you should add this JavaScript.. Or add it to master page to handle dynamically.. Just use google to find 1. How to get page URL using JavaScript 2. Hiding page elements using JavaScript

Comment: Ok I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use JavaScript on each page and hide it on page load.

On each page you should add this JavaScript.. Or add it to master page to handle dynamically.